# MySQL query not updating db not matter what I try

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help assist me with getting my query below to update db from php?  Everything I try does not work....Here is my code....

```
$db->query("UPDATE users SET `status` = Active WHERE user_name = {$email} ")or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hint:  Use quotes around string constants.

Comment: For a start, please provide the whole code. Do you have some kind of error reporting active? Also, I see that you are using the _mysql_ extension for data access. Please note that it was removed as of PHP 7.0.0 and replaced with the extension _mysqli_.

Comment: You should use parametrized queries instead of substituting variables. It will solve this problem, and also prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: @dakis He's using `mysqli`, not `mysql`. The obsolete mysql extension doesn't have an OO interface.

Comment: `mysql_error()` should be `$db->error`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I saw [mysql_error](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php), so I concluded it's _mysql_ extension. I didn't look into _query_ though. It doesn't exist as _mysql_ method, indeed.

Answer (score -1):

Try it with quotes around the strings in the query

```
$db->query("UPDATE users SET status = 'Active' WHERE user_name = '{$email}' ")or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
```